# LIST INDICES ERROR In Python 2.7, Please suggest solution for OPTION 1 in code

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary, indices

Hi I have a doubt in calling a function with string name as it is showing error: LIST INDICES MUST BE AN INTEGER

I agree with the error statement but don't have the clue what to do. As when I am giving function argument parameter as a Dictionary , (option 2), its function is accepting it and running the code smoothly.
But on giving it just the name of the key (as a I did in option 1), it is showing Indices error because I am accessing key which is a string not integer & it doesn't have the key with value (which is an error of unhashable key).
So,

Please explain me following:

How to create a dictionary with key name but empty value.
How to compare whether it is a list name is given in arguments of the function or a dictionary key. Please suggest code.
Solution of my code. FOR OPTION 1

Code:

```
 # CODE FOR DETRMINING PRICE AS PER STOCK
#PYTHON 2.7 SCRIPT 
stock = {
    "banana": 6,
    "apple": 0,
    "orange": 32,
    "pear": 15
}

prices = {
    "banana": 4,
    "apple": 2,
    "orange": 1.5,
    "pear": 3
}

def compute_bill(food):
    x = 0
    total1 = 0
    total2 = 0
    z=0

    for key in food: # I KNOW I AM DOING ERROR HERE, BUT NO CLUE WHAT TO DO!!

        count = stock[key] #INTIAL COUNT
        print "this is the stock of %s : %d " % (key,count)

        count = stock[key] - food[key] # STOCK REMAINING
        print "this is the stock remaining of %s : %d " % (key,count)

        if count > 0: # CHECKING WHETHER IT IS IN STOCK OR NOT
            z = prices[key] * food[key] # FINDING TOTAL
            total1 = z + total1 # ACCUMLATING TOTAL
            print "this is the total1 of %s : %f \n" % (key,z)

        elif count <= 0: # OVER-STOCK OR EMPTY STOCK
            z = prices[key] * stock[key]
            total2 = z + total2
            print "this is the total2 of %s : %f \n" % (key,z)

        x = total1 + total2 #COMPUTING WHOLE TOTAL



    print "\n this is the whole total : %f \n" % x

    return x



 # JST WANT ALL PEAR
compute_bill(['pear']) #OPTION 1: NOT WORKING!! NEED SOLUTION

#OPTION 2 : WORKING : 
order = {'apple' : 1, 'banana' : 3, 'pear' : 3, 'orange' : 3}
    compute_bill(order)
```

Advance Thanks & Cheers!!

Comment: It wouldn't hurt if you stated your problem in a more structured fashion.  This is more a stream of consciousness ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check whether the passed in object is a dictionary (an `order`) or a list (an `item`) ... You also need to decide exactly what behavior you want in the second case, but let me guess you want to answer with the total price for the available stock:

```py
def compute_bill(food):
    if isinstance(food, dict):
        compute_bill_for_order(food)
    if isinstance(food, list):
        compute_bill_for_items(food)

def compute_bill_for_order(order):
    for key in order.keys():  ## You also have to call the `keys` method
      # Here goes the exact same code you have for the cases
      # count > 0 and count <= 0
      # Basically, the `compute_bill` method
      pass

def compute_bill_for_items(items):
    total = 0
    for item in items:
        total += prices[item] * stock[item]
    return total
```

Comment: Voilla!! It works!! So, basically we need to define two functions separately to check them. Thanks logc!! :) Now I got the logic.

Comment: `type(food) == list` and `type(food) == dict` should also work by the way, although using `isinstance()` is recommended.

Comment: @MichielKauw-A-Tjoe thanks for your comment!  I was writing off the top of my head and did not take the time to look for the recommended way to check types.  I edited the answer to improve it based on your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

It means that you are passing something other than an integer as a list index. From the look of it, `compute_bill()` is called with a string called `'pear'` inside a list. The list is then passed as the parameter `food`. Then the `for` statement takes the `'pear'` string as a key, which is correct if you apply it to the dictionary `stock`. However, `food` is still a list, so calling `food['pear']` will give the error. It should be `food[0]`. You could substitute the loop with this one:

```
    for i in range(len(food)):
        key = food[i]
```

After that you're able to access both the list and the dictionary with the index `i` and the key `key` respectively. In that case `food[0]` doesn't result in an integer value but with the string `'pear'`.

Comment: Not sure what you mean but it seems like you figured it out already.

Answer (score 0):

As the start of each iteration when looping through your food items, in the `compute_bill` function, I would extract the quantity of desired food :

```
try:
  quantity = food[key]  # get only how much was asked
except TypeError:
  quantity = stock[key] # get all remaining food from the stock !
```

Then, wherever you have used `food[key]`, use the new variable `quantity`.

Comment: Basically the problem was in for loop!! as it was iterating key in my function. So, I need to change it according to the input given i.e whether it is a dictionary or list. Anyways, I got the solution. Thanks for your help! :)